# Parse empty value as custom value when reading CSV file using OpenCSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I am parsing a CSV file which is separated by | and having a heading with column name. There can be some empty data as well which will be separated by two delimeters. I am using below code to parse CSV and it sets field as null it case of no data for some heading but I want to set it as blank or custom value instead of null.

```
HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy ms = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy();
ms.setType(clazz);

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

CsvToBean cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
        .withType(clazz)
        .withMappingStrategy(ms)
        .withSkipLines(0)
        .withSeparator('|')
        .build();

cb.parse();
```

Comment: Theoretically you should set empty values with ``.withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.NEITHER)``. At least in version 4.6 this is the [default](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/enums/CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.html).

Comment: You are right I am able to get blank data but I want to have custom data. I think I will have to replace the blank after CsvTobean parsing is done.

Comment: As far as I have seen of OpenCSV, that would be the easiest way. You could also extend the ``CSVParser`` and overwrite the ``convertToCsvValue`` method. But then you would also have to extend ``CsvToBeanBuilder`` and ``CSVParserBuilder`` to insert your parser.